# Move QED symbol to the left, i.e. at the end of the sentence

Tags: symbols, amsmath, theorems, amsthm

I want to make the qed symbol at the end of a proof appear at the end of the last sentence, not at the far right of the same line.

Would like to do this the simplest way possible.

All I can find online is people using `\qedhere` to fix the symbol being on the wrong line.

Comment: Do you want this just for a single `proof`?

Comment: no, but the single case would be sufficient, I can copy/paste for others.  I don't really want to create a new environment or change the existing one because i'll forget what to do if I reformat laptop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can redefine it to simply (Thanks to @egreg who pointed out the need for `\unskip\nobreak`)

```
\renewcommand{\qed}{\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol}%
```

Here's a (not so minimal) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\renewcommand{\qed}{\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol}% As suggested by egreg

\begin{document}

\begin{proof} A Simple Proof
Here is my proof
\end{proof}

\begin{proof} A Long Proof
Here is my very long proof that involves a lot of computation and stretches quite far to the margin.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof} A Proof with Equations (\verb!equation! environment)
Here is my proof:

\begin{equation}
  x = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1
          + \cfrac{1}{a_2
          + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}}
\end{equation}
\end{proof}


\begin{proof} A Proof with Equations (\verb!equation! environment) and \verb!\qedhere!
Here is my proof:

\begin{equation}
  x = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1
          + \cfrac{1}{a_2
          + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + a_4}}}
  \qedhere
\end{equation}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof} A Proof with aligned equations (\verb!align! environment)
\begin{align}
\intertext{If}
   A &= \sigma_1+\sigma_2\\
   B &= \rho_1+\rho_2\\
\intertext{then}
C(x) &= e^{Ax^2+\pi}+B
\end{align}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof} A Proof with aligned equations (\verb!align! environment) and \verb!\qedhere!
\begin{align}
\intertext{If}
   A &= \sigma_1+\sigma_2\\
   B &= \rho_1+\rho_2\\
\intertext{then}
C(x) &= e^{Ax^2+\pi}+B\qedhere
\end{align}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: QED symbol replacement examples]

### ISSUES

If your proof has equations, you should use `\qedhere` to avoid that the symbol goes to the next line (as @egreg suggested, it's not a good idea to add  `\qedhere` to all equation environments)

Comment: That redefinition of `\qed` can lead to perhaps an unwanted "dangling qed symbol" by itself on a new line if the last line of the proof itself is too long. For example, in the MWE replace `Here is my proof` with `Here is my very long proof that involves a lot of computation and stretches quite far to the margin.`

Comment: And this also breaks the logic crafted in the `amsthm` package for placing the tombstone symbol when the last line of the proof is a displayed equation (the symbol gets placed on the next line). Of course, one can always re-write the proof so that the last line is prose...

Comment: @WillieWong WOuld it be okay to have the que symbol next to the equation's first line? If so loading `etoolbox` and calling `\qedhere` right before the end of the environment (for `\qedhere` suppress the `\qed` behaviour) should work (`\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{\qedhere}` and `\AtEndEnvironment{equation*}{\qedhere}`)

Comment: You're at least missing `\unskip` and `\nobreak`: `\renewcommand{\qed}{\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol}`. Otherwise it may result in a lonely tombstone symbol at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add `\qedhere` to all `equation` environments: `\qedhere` should be added where needed. With your code, if you have an `equation` environments in a single proof, it will be marked, independently of it being at the end of the proof; if there are two, the *first* one will be marked. Please, remove that part.

Comment: In your MWE, I think you meant to use `[...]` rather than `{...}` for the optional argument to the `proof` environments.  Otherwise you might as well just leave out the braces altogether.  (Not sure whether `\verb` will work in the argument, though.)

Comment: For some reason I get an error message saying that "I can't use unskip in vertical mode" when I use the code `\renewcommand{\qed}{\unskip\nobreak\quad\qedsymbol}%`, when using an align enviroment inside the proof environment.

Comment: @AriBrodsky You're absolutelly right (twice), I fixed the MWE to remove the argument.

Comment: @Emilio, I couldn't reproduce the problem, see the updated MWE.

Comment: @Emilio BTW, perhaps a `\leavevmode` before `\unskip` won't hurt, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @henrique -- i think (without testing) that `\leavevmode` will render the `\unskip` inoperative.  better would be a test for `\ifhmode`, and perform `\unskip` only if that's true.  (but if it's really vertical mode, the tombstone will surely end up on a line by itself, possibly even on a new page.  not at all nice.)

Comment: @Emilio, please take a look at barbara's comment above.

Comment: @henrique But I tried `\leavevmode` and it works, while ommitting it or `\unskip` altogether doesn't.